# How to display file from remote url inside a xamarin.ios app

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

How to display a file (pdf,txt,doc..) from remote url inside a xamarin.ios app?

i need to display a file inside a application, can anybody help me ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: https://blog.xamarin.com/previewing-files-with-xamarin-ios/

Comment: this one explaining how to preview local file. but i need how to preview a file from remote url like http://css4.pub/2015/icelandic/dictionary.pdf

Comment: load them into a webview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

As **Jason** said, load your files into a `webView` I would show the code for you:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();
            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

            var  webView = new UIWebView(View.Bounds);
            View.AddSubview(webView);

            var url = "http://css4.pub/2015/icelandic/dictionary.pdf"; // NOTE: https secure request
            webView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(url)));
        }
```

> Because ATS is enabled by default in iOS 9 and OS X El Capitan, if
>   your Xamarin.iOS app or any library or service it is using makes
>   connection to the internet, you'll need to take some action or your
>   connections will result in an exception being thrown.

Pay attention to the `ATS` setting in your app as your website begin with `http` instead of `https`.

Add the following to your app's `Info.plist` file to allow web pages to load correctly while `Apple Transport Security (ATS)` protection is still enabled for the rest of the app:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key> NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Refer: [opting-out-of-ats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/ats#opting-out-of-ats)